# Why is て used here?

Tags: translation, meaning, word-choice

I got this message after asking for recommendations for Japanese media:

> 海猿て映画はオススメかな

My question is, why is there a て after 海猿？I was thinking it was apart of the title but 猿 doesn’t need a て. Does it just connect the title with the fact that it’s a movie?

Like “I recommend the movie ‘Sea Monkey’”. Some sort of abbreviation of って？

Comment: Yes, abbreviation of って（いう）.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just as you think, it means “I recommend the movie ‘Sea Monkey.”
In this sentence, て means って or という.
I think this abbreviation is often used in Kansai.